# Apache authentication from multiple domains in AD with mod_authn_alias

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-auth-ldap, mod-authn-alias

I'm running Apache 2 and I need to authentificate users from multiple AD domains in one `<Location/>`. I tried using [mod_authn_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html)

ОС: Debian GNU/Linux Squueze with lastest updates
Apache/2.2.16

Modules

/etc/apache2/apache.conf:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap first-ldap>
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://win2003server:389/DC=first,DC=domain?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=user1,cn=Users,dc=first,dc=domain"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "user1"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap second-ldap>
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://win2008server:3268/DC=second,DC=domain?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=user2,cn=Users,dc=second,dc=domain"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "user2"
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000default:

```
<Location /test>

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    Authtype Basic
    AuthBasicProvider first-ldap second-ldap
    AuthName "TEST"
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    require valid-user

</Location>
```

With this configuration it authentificates users from first domain, and for users from second domain it igves an error:

```
 [Fri Sep 16 20:54:39 2011] [info] [client 10.0.0.62] [25672] auth_ldap authenticate: user2 user2 authentication failed; URI /test/ [ldap_simple_bind_s() to check user2 credentials failed][Invalid credentials]
```

When I leave only `AuthBasicProvider second-ldap` users from second domain can authntificate successfully, so second domain LDAP is OK.

Does any one know solution to force mod_authn_alias to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found way to solution here: [authenticating-apache-httpd-against-multiple-ldap-servers-with-expired-accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/140858/authenticating-apache-httpd-against-multiple-ldap-servers-with-expired-accounts)

I used for testing user account from second domain, that had namesake disabled account in first domain. Deletion of disabled account helped, but deleting accounts in AD domain is bad practice: you can receive objects with unknown security descriptors. I created LDAP filter for elimination of disabled users, and now everything works fine :)

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap first-ldap>
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://win2003server:389/DC=first,DC=domain?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=user1,cn=Users,dc=first,dc=domain"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "user1"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap second-ldap>
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://win2008server:3268/DC=second,DC=domain?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=user2,cn=Users,dc=second,dc=domain"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "user2"
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

Note, that this filter works for AD domain with functional level "windows 2000 native", and doesn't work for AD domain with functional level "windows server 2003", I don't know why.

Comment: The "u" in userAccountControl should be capitalized (!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))

Comment: @oyarzun : I do not manage that servers anymore, but it worked for me as written here. It was AD on Windows 2003.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make Apache do what you want.  However, you can set up OpenLDAP as a proxy in front of multiple AD instances using either the `ldap` or `meta` backends, and this will get you effectively the same behavior.  You point Apache at your OpenLDAP proxy, and then OpenLDAP talks to your AD servers.

[Here](http://blog.oddbit.com/2010/02/merging-directories-with-openldap-meta.html) is my write-up on using the `meta` backend.  This is more of a starting point than an actual solution.

I'm  actually using OpenLDAP as a proxy right now to authenticate against three separate directories -- one AD domain, one remote LDAP server, and a local LDAP directory.

Comment: Thank you for answer :) I will probably use this solution, if I won't found a way to make mod_authn_alias work. But it's overkill for this task and it creates additional single point of failure, which decreases whole infrastructure stability.